# SQLAlchemy ProgrammingError - how to debug?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 0.5.8, and seeing this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt 'INSERT INTO enumeration_value (id,
key_id, code, name, notes) VALUES (%(id)s, %(key_id)s, %(code)s, %(name)s, %(notes)s)' 
{'key_id': 'aac6fc29-4ccd-4fe4-9118-cfbbd04449fe', 'notes': '', 'code': (u'Barnet',), 
'id': 'd0540c97-882e-4a5b-bf14-b3ebcfeea051', 'name': (u'Barnet',)}
```

But a direct SQL insert with the values from the error seems to work just fine:

```
=> INSERT INTO enumeration_value (id, key_id, code, name, notes) 
VALUES ('d0540c97-882e-4a5b-bf14-b3ebcfeea051', 'aac6fc29-4ccd-4fe4-9118-cfbbd04449fe', 
'Barnet', 'Barnet', '');
INSERT 0 1
```

If the direct SQL works OK, how can I start to debug this?

Incidentally, the line that's throwing the error doesn't seem to have an INSERT statement in it at all, so I am a bit confused:

```
  File "----barnet.py", line 117, in load_file
    instance = model.Session.query(model.EnumerationValue).filter_by(key=key_barnet_level_2, code=level_2).all()
```

Do SQLAlchemy filter statements generate INSERT commands, or does this just happen to be the last line before things start to go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - the problem was actually a syntax error a few lines higher up, with a rogue comma:

```
key_from = code,
```

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time. Please close the question.